# FileStream on cluster gives me an exception

Tags: spark-streaming

I am writing a Spark STreaming application using file stream...

```
val probeFileLines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/data-sources/DXE_Ver/1.4/MTN_Abuja/DXE/20160221/HTTP", filterF, false) //.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
```

But I get exception error for file/IO..for

```
16/09/07 10:20:30 WARN FileInputDStream: Error finding new files
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mapr/cellos-mapr/data-sources/DXE_Ver/1.4/MTN_Abuja/DXE/20160221/HTTP
        at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.listMapRStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1486)
        at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.listStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1523)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.listStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:86)
```

While the directory exist in my cluster.

I am running my job using spark submit

```
spark-submit --class "StreamingEngineSt"  target/scala-2.11/sprkhbase_2.11-1.0.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to file permissions or ownership(May be need hdfs user).

Comment: When I use.. val probeFileLines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("hdfs://data-sources/DXE_Ver/1.4/MTN_Abuja/DXE/20160221/HTTP", filterF, false)..it gives me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: data-sources
can some one give me an hint on proper use of the argument..I dont think it is due to permissions or ownerships